# how can I Get Picklist Dropdown in vfp

Tags: visualforce

```
Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!SmartFarmingRole}"/>
```

its Controller is:

```
public class CommunitiesSelfRegController {

    public String SmartFarmingRole { get; set; } 
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    
    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {
        String expid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('expid');            
        if (expId != null) {
            Site.setExperienceId(expId); 
        }    
    }
    
    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {
    
           // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

        String profileId = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.
        
        String userName = email;

        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.Smart_Farming_Role__c = SmartFarmingRole;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;
        
        String userId;

        try {
            userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);
        } catch(Site.ExternalUserCreateException ex) {
            List<String> errors = ex.getDisplayMessages();
            for (String error : errors)  {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, error));
            }
            
            // This message is used for debugging. Do not display this in the UI to the end user.
            // It has the information around why the user creation failed.
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you use apex:inputField/apex:outputField only with object fields. You'd want to use the field directly, if accessible:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!User.Smart_Farming_Role__c}" />
```

If that's not possible, the next best option would be to use a select list. Create the options in Apex:

```
public SelectOption[] smartFarmingRoleOptions { get; set; }
```

...

```
public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {
  String expid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('expid');            
  if(expId != null) {
    Site.setExperienceId(expId); 
  }
  smartFarmingRoleOptions = new SelectOption[0];
  for(PicklistEntry entry: sObjectType.User.fields.Smart_Farming_Role__c.getPicklistValues()) {
    smartFarmingRoleOptions.add(
      new SelectOption(
        entry.getValue(), 
        entry.getLabel()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Then expose those in the UI:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!SmartFarmingRole}">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!smartFarmingRoleOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: `for(PicklistEntry entry: sObjectType.User.fields.Smart_Farming_Role__c.getPicklistValues()) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(entry.getValue(), entry.getLabel()));
          }`    it shows error!  Variable doesnot exist.

Comment: @Danish_46 That was a copy-paste error. Try `smartFarmingRoleOptions.add(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot.. it works fine